# Reading multiple lines in Bourne Shell

Tags: shell-script, shell, bourne-shell

I'm trying to read two lines into two variables. In Bash I would use something like this:

```
cat << EOF > myfile
line1
line2
EOF

cat myfile |  {
 read firstline
 echo $firstline # "line1" in bash and sh
 read secondline
}

echo $firstline # "line1" in bash, empty in sh
echo $secondline
```

In Bourne Shell however `$firstline` and `$secondline` are empty outside the command group. How can I do it in sh?

Comment: To be clear; the file you're reading from only contains two lines and are the lines terminate "\n"?

Comment: `$firstline` should be empty in `bash` as well at the end. Did you set `firstline` before running this code? Unset it with `unset firstline` and try again.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468177/bin-sh-read-variable-from-pipe

Comment: No, it doesn't print the value of variables outside the `{...}` in bash, unless you have the `shopt -s lastpipe` set. Posix shells also do not print that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(You most likely have `firstline` set already when you tested that code in `bash`, its value should be empty at the end).

When running the pipeline

```
cat myfile | { read firstline; read secondline; }
```

the right hand side is running in a subshell.  Not because of the `{ ...; }` but because it's part of a pipeline.  The subshell environment will contain the two variables `firstline` and `secondline` (after both have been read), but will be destroyed when the subshell terminates, discarding both variables.

This holds true for both POSIX `sh` and `bash`.

In `bash` (4.2+), you can work around this by setting the `lastpipe` shell option. From the `bash` manual:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in
>   a subshell).  See COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT for a description of a
>   subshell environment.  If the `lastpipe` option is enabled using the
>   `shopt` builtin (see the description of `shopt` below), the last element of
>   a pipeline may be run by the shell process.

This would work in a script, but not in an interactive shell with job control enabled (it's the job control that makes it not work, not the interactivity).

Example:

```
$ cat script.sh
cat << EOF > myfile
line1
line2
EOF

cat myfile | { read firstline; read secondline; }
printf 'first=%s\n' "$firstline"
printf 'second=%s\n' "$secondline"

shopt -s lastpipe
cat myfile | { read firstline; read secondline; }
printf 'first=%s\n' "$firstline"
printf 'second=%s\n' "$secondline"
```

```bash
$ bash script.sh
first=
second=
first=line1
second=line2
```

In your particular case, you could also, in both POSIX `sh` and `bash`, do away with `cat` and the pipe completely and instead redirect into the compound command with the two `read` calls directly:

```sh
{ read firstline; read secondline; } <myfile
```

On a tangential note, you most likely do not have a real historical Bourne shell on your machine (unless it's a Solaris system before Solaris 11).  I'm assuming you mean a modern POSIX `sh` shell.

Comment: The question was about the `Bourne Shell` but your proposed solution does not work with the `Bourne Shell`. BTW: Jobcontrol needs to be manually enabled in the Bourne Shell, even when it is in interactive mode.

Comment: You are right, didn't know that there is a difference between the original Bourne Shell and sh. I'm on Alpine, not Solaris.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the right side of a pipe, there are some limitations.

I changed your code to ensure that the variables were unset before use, and compressed it a little bit.

```bsh
#! /bin/sh

unset firstline secondline
printf '%s\n%s\n' line1 line2 > myfile

cat myfile | { read firstline; read secondline
               echo "internal 1: $firstline"     # "line1" in most shells
               echo "internal 2: $secondline"    # "line2" in most shells
             }

echo "Outside 1: $firstline"     # "line1" in ksh, zsh (even called as sh).
                                 #  Empty in sh, bash, mksh, dash, ash, yash.
echo "Outside 2: $secondline"    # "line2" in ksh, zsh.
                                 # Same as above for other shells.
```

Internals to the compound command `{...}` had values, external (`Outside`) were empty in many cases (especially POSIX, the portable case).

Only if you set `shopt -s lastpipe` you get bash to keep the values on the right side of the pipe symbol. Both ksh(93) and zsh keep the values read by default.

So, the problem is to avoid the pipe `|` symbol, well, in this case it is very simple. Either `<file { ... }` or `{...} <file` and you are set to keep the value of variables portably.

```bsh
#! /bin/sh

unset firstline secondline
printf '%s\n%s\n' line1 line2 > myfile

{ read firstline; read secondline
  printf '%s\n' "internal 1: $firstline"     # "line1" in most shells
  printf '%s\n' "internal 2: $secondline"    # "line2" in most shells
} < myfile

printf '%s\n' "Outside 1: $firstline"          # "line1" in most shells.
printf '%s\n' "Outside 2: $secondline"         # "line2" in most shells.
```

That worket in all shells tested except the old Bourne shell (it lacks the {...} structure that runs in the present shell, the workaround becomes more difficult, not worth the time, read @schily answer for that).

Comment: +1 Very nice, in particular the "disquisition" on misc. "post-Bourne" shells at end of 1st code-block. Tx.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using `read` in the `Bourne Shell` since the Bourne Shell has two limitations:

- The right side of a pipeline is always run in a subshell

  With `echo foo | read VAR`, the `read` command is always run in a subshell
- The Bourne Shell places command lists with shell builtin commands in `{ ...; }` into a subshell. So

  `{ read A; read B; } < file` is also run in a subshell.

If you like to verify this, I recommend you to check this with `obosh` from the `schilytools`, which is a highly portable version of the Solaris Bourne Shell.

See: http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/

Modern shells (starting with `ksh93` run the rightmost program of a pipeline inside the main shell process in case this is a shell builtin. So when you use the recent version of the Bourne Shell (`bosh`), this works for you. `bosh` also does not create a subshell for `{ ...; }` for performance reasons and this has the side effect that

```
{ read A; read B; } < file
```

works with `bosh`

The following should work with all shells:

```
exec 3<&0               # save standard input as fd 3
exec < file             # use file as stdin
read A
read B
exec 0<&3               # restore standard input
exec 3<&-               # close file descriptor 3
```

Comment: Why does this correct answer get a downvote and an incorrect answer gets an upvote? My answer is easy to verify...`obosh` runs nearly anywhere.

Comment: Quite right, I did not read that accurately.

Comment: +1 @schily you do answer the question and provide a bourne solution, so, I see no issue here to downvote (I upvoted).